# Add time in magento2

Tags: magento2

when i place order it shows me country time and i have another module purhcase order its shows me server date time

```
$order_model->setCreatedAt($this->_date->gmtDate());
```

Comment: what u exactly want?

Comment: i want country time date not sever time

Comment: this showing me server time

Answer (score 0):

The following should be locale time and not server time

So for example in UK BST which is GMT plus 1

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $dateTime
    ) {
        $this->dateTime = $dateTime;
    }
```

```
echo __('%1 GMT', $this->dateTime->gmtDate());
```